# How to send response with javascript to draw html elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a script like twitter in which user just provide an id and all his/her tweets get loaded on site where the script inserted.

What I've done is

> User should copy this code to load my widget

```
<a class="getStarted" data-getStartedID="123456789">Get Started App ID</a>

<script>
!function(d,s,id){
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
        if(!d.getElementById(id)){
            js=d.createElement(s);
            js.id=id;
            js.src=p+"://localhost/practices/js_practice/siteOpen.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
}}(document,"script","getStarted-C");
```

> My `siteOpen.js` is as below :

```
!function(d){

var a = d.getElementsByClassName('getStarted');
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("getStarted")[0].getAttribute("data-getStartedID");
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
var appID = x;
r.open("POST", "openwebIndex.php", true);
r.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
r.setRequestHeader("Content-length", appID.length);
r.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

r.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200) return;
    if(r.responseText.trim()==1){
        return '<p>output to be draw on where script is pasted</p>';
        if(console)console.info('Valid appID');
    }

};
  r.send('appID='+appID);
}(document);
```

i don't know what to do to send the response and load/draw my widget on user's website.

My response will be in html elements. 
Please suggest me what should i do. I just stuck at this point.

**EDIT**

I'm getting `object HTMLScriptElement` when I alert  `js` variable.

Comment: Does your server support cross-origing requests?

Comment: If the problem is because of cross origin then it will get displayed in my console. But there is not any error.

Comment: Do you get anything in the console? How about the traffic/timeline information?

Comment: nope! I am building it like how twitter's code works. Not for twitter's tweets.

Comment: I get errors in the console (Refused to set unsafe header) but I guess it could be a server setting. Apart from that, it works fine for me after I correct two things: the paths are incorrect (openwebIndex.php in particular), and moving the `return` to after the `console.info` (anything after the `return` will not be executed because you'll have exited the function already)

Comment: You mean you get a p tag on your current page  as response ?

Comment: @VedPandya can't you just append the html content to the body tag. Did u tried that ?

Comment: The user can be on any site who wants to use my widget. And i have to first validate that user on my site with his given App Id and then i have to pass data stored for that user only.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying adding the html code in the body tag.

users html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

<script src="widget.js"></script>
```

Your `widget.js`

```
//  var appId = d.getElementsByClassName('getStarted');
//  process the app id and make the output here
var output = "<div>This is the content of the widget</div>";
document.body.innerHTML += output;
```

This will show the content in the users html file. If you have cross domain issue, use `JSONP` for resolving that.

Comment: The content is not same for any user. Each user must have different layout. And in this method the content will be same. :(

Comment: You need to process the content. get the app Id, do what ever stuff u need to do and then make the final output. And then just append the final output to the body. By this you can make dynamic content for each user.